# PHP zip_open what temporary directory is it using for the temp files

Tags: php

How can I find out the temporary directory that zip_open is using to temporary hold the
extracted files. 
Is there a way to extract this from a resource handler getrieved from this:

```
 $zip = zip_open($src_file)
 while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
```

$zip_entry - being the zip resource handler

I suspect it is not using the php temporary directory, that I can check from

```
sys_get_temp_dir();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, that function doesn't actually "extract" the files before reading them as it can essentially decompress them on-the-fly.  You can read up on the compression algorithm used [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE).

If you're using the [ZipArchive class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) which supports extracting, building, and adding to .zip archives, then you'll be using a temp directory.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.